# Manipulate DOM Element that raises an event

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs

If I have this code:

```
<li ng-repeat='i in items'>
    <a ng-click='doSomething(i.id)'>link</a>
</li>
```

and this JS:

```
function doSomething(objId) {
    $.ajax({ url: 'myUrl.php', success: successHandler});
}

function successHandler(response) {
 // do something with the response
}
```

The user clicks on the link, which changes class, an AJAX request is made, then a success handler is called (I've omitted the error handler for brevity).

I need some clean way to access the `<li>` element whose child originated the click event in both functions:

1. in `doSomething()` (for example to write "loading..." and add a "loading" CSS class, maybe with `ng-class`)
2. in `successHandler()` (if success, remove "loading..." and remove the class)

What is the best way to achieve this? I've tried:

- using data- attributes (I cannot manipulate them in Angular and don't solve the problem)
- using global variables (whoa, bad)
- using scope variables, like `$scope.currentClickedItem`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend not to access dom element directly. Best way to do achieve your goal in angular is:

html:

```
<li ng-repeat='i in items'>
    <a ng-click='doSomething(i)' ng-class="{active: i.isActive}">link</a>
</li>
```

js:

```
function doSomething(obj) {
    $.ajax({ url: 'myUrl.php', success: successHandler.bind(this, obj});
}

function successHandler(obj, response) {
    // do anything with the response and object
    obj.isActive = true;
}
```

But anyhow, you want to access dom:

You can use angular $event object to access clicked element. if you need to access `<li>`, element.parentElement is your friend.

html:

```
<li ng-repeat='i in items'>
    <a ng-click='doSomething(i.id, $event)'>link</a>
</li>
```

js:

```
function doSomething(objId, $event) {
    var element = $event.target;
    $.ajax({ url: 'myUrl.php', success: successHandler.bind(this, element});
}

function successHandler(element, response) {
    // do anything with the response and element
}
```

bind method's first argument can be `null` instead of `this` if they do not need to share same scope.

Comment: Yes, right now I was trying with the event object. But I'd never have thought of the *second* part with `.bind()`! Really interesting, many many thanks

Comment: I edited my answer without seeing Razzildinho's answer. For angular accessing elements without a certain need of deep dom manipulation is not a good way.

Comment: Yes, I was on an almost identical solution too (I didn't see Razzildinho's answer either!)

Answer (score 2):

You can manipulate the object rather than the element.

```
<li ng-repeat='i in items'>
  <a ng-class="i.loading ? 'loading' : ''" ng-click='doSomething(i)'>link</a>
</li>
```

JS

```
function doSomething(obj) {
    obj.loading = true;
    var objId = obj.id;
    $.ajax({ url: 'myUrl.php', success: successHandler});
}

function successHandler(response) {
    // do something with the response
}
```

Comment: You can obiously pass `obj` into the `successHandler` to make `obj.loading = false;`.

Comment: Better way to do this. I haven't seen your answer while editing mine.

Comment: I answered my own questin but didn't see yours either, it seems we had a similar solution! anyway thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I will answer my own question but leaving @CKK's one as "answered".
There's no need to manipulate the element in `doSomething()` because I can do:

```
<li ng-class='i.class' ng-repeat='i in items'>
   {{ i.message }}
   <a ng-click='doSomething(i)'>...</a>
</li>
```

Javascript:

```
function doSomething(obj)
{
     obj.class='loading-class';
     obj.message="Loading...";
    // ajax call...
}
```